# Data Refinery states I have maxed out my data limits. any way to clear/reset?

Tags: watson, ibm-data-refinery

I am trying to set up a data connection for Watson Analytics and IBM Data Refinery states I have maxed out my data limits. Is there a way to clear or reset?

Answer (score 0):

The default IBM Cloud account type, known as a Lite account, provides access to all IBM Cloud based services that provide a Lite plan option. Those plans provide free, but limited, access to services. For Data Refinery (part of the Watson Knowledge Catalog & Watson Studio services), the lite plan has a limit of 50 Capacity Unit Hours per month. The message you're seeing appears when you have reached the limit of the free usage the plan provides. The limit is reset each calendar month and can be removed by upgrading your IBM Cloud account and associated service plan(s)

You can check which plan your services are on via this link:
https://dataplatform.ibm.com/console/overview

For information on account types, see here:
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/account/index.html#accounts

For information on changing service plans, see here:
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/account/change-plan.html#changing

For information on Capacity Unit Hours in relation to Data Flows (which Data Refinery creates), see here:
https://www.ibm.com/cloud/watson-knowledge-catalog/faq